# Using VPN router and VPN access point or VPN switch to allow using VPN for any wireless or Ethernet capable devices?

Tags: vpn, wireless-access-point, switch

I wanted to pre-order a game on Nintendo Switch, but I am not sure if they checked my IP and tell that I am not Oct 29 in USA yet... even thought I already set my region to Asia and my timezone to Asia.  So I cannot pre-order it yet.  (the current USA time is Oct 28, and the current Asia time is Oct 29).

So is it true that I can use some VPN router, VPN access point, or VPN switch to make myself use VPN even when Nintendo Switch has no VPN function?  I think for my Mac or PC or smartphone, they are more ready to use VPN, but Nintendo Switch or my smart TV (such as the Samsung ones) may not have VPN functions.

But in general I saw VPN routers being sold on Amazon, but not VPN Access Point or VPN Switches.  It seems like it has to be a router, be it Wireless or non-Wireless.  But my experience is that if I use an access point, my MacBook can set up a web server, and any computer on any access point at home can connect to it, but if my MacBook is connected to a wireless router, then only devices connected to this wireless router can access the website, because the router makes it having its "own little world"... even if I turn off the firewall, it may have its own world of DHCP server and local IP address, I am not sure, but access point just make it as if it is one big happy family. (as if everybody is plugged into the same 64 port Ethernet switch).

So is there a wireless access point or switch that can do VPN?  I saw the term VPN server and think it means that, except the VPN server function is on a router device... so it is not access point or plain switch.

Comment: This sounds like a very convoluted [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) for an issue that can be solved by simply waiting a day.

Comment: we are here concerned with a solution. We are not here to debate a personal preference of whether to wait a day or not wait a day.  What if it is for some other purpose? What if it is just to make it work so that any device at home doesn't need to set up VPN separately?  Are you going to impose your personal preference to stop a solution? Making the world a better place?

Comment: You're concerned with a solution to a problem you have not fully defined. Is there an AP with VPN? Aside from it being a 'shopping question' & therefore off-topic, the answer is probably 'no' because it is not a functionality necessarily applicable to that technology. AP connects to router, router can do the VPN. What makes this an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) is that you have come up with what you think is the solution to your problem & are asking about that, when you should be asking about your problem itself. BTW, it's now the 29th right across the US.

Comment: My question is so very simple, "Can we use a wireless access point or switch with VPN so that it can use VPN and make all our other devices connected to it be using the VPN.  It seems there are only 'routers' that can do that." But you have to attack my question to make yourself right

Comment: If this is a hardware recommendation question, then it is indeed [off-topic here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Otherwise, unless you have a really scaled down router, your current router probably already has support for configuring a VPN that it will use for all traffic, which means you wouldn't need any other hardware to do this. If you have questions about how to set that up specifically, then you should ask a new question with the specific details regarding that.

Comment: this is about how to make it work... for example, I just thought about, if we can get a VPN router, and often, there are settings that can let the router work as an access point, maybe that'd work. Or, would it work if it is VPN but as access point? Because then what does it mean that some devices on this LAN is using regular Internet, but some are using VPN? Maybe an extra layer is needed, which is the DHCP layer (the router layer), which I am not sure